# Paypal discount_rate_cart and tax_rate conflict?

Tags: html, paypal

Here's my line of code for Paypal Variables.

```
paypal:{'business':'remax@danalcoimpressions.com','discount_rate_cart':'50','tax_rate':'5', 'currency_code':'CAD', 'country':'CA','locale.x':'fr_CA'},
```

It seems like I can't use the `tax_rate` variable with the `discount_rate_cart`.
I tried using `tax_cart`, and it's working, but it's only adding the tax to the total. I need it to be multiplied by the tax value.

When it comes to Paypal, only the discount_rate_cart is working. The tax does not appear at all. Everything's working well by the way, so no need to see the rest of the code. It's only about adding these Paypal variables.

Is that possible that I can't use 2 type of rate at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct.

`discount_rate_cart` and `tax_rate conflict` are in conflict with each other and you could consider adding discount rates to each item.